# Returning to Schengen after overstaying in Sweden by 12 days

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, overstaying

I am in Ethiopia now but I had been Sweden in march 2017. Is was my first time in the Schengen area. And I stayed 32 days, but the duration of stay in my passport was 20 days. Honestly I have misunderstandings of the staring visa date from to until and the stay of duration. In my thinking, I can stay until validation period and I return back my home before validity date. So I applied for another Schengen visa, and they rejected my application because of this reason. So how can I get a Schengen visa again?

Answer (score 4):

It was your responsibility to understand the terms of your visa. You failed. So what can you do now?

- Do not apply again until you have a **stable, well-paid** job where you live. The overstay is a big factor in the decision, so everything else must look good.
- Travel to countries near you, without overstays or similar incidents.
- Wait a **long** time before you make the next application.
- Be honest in your next application, mention that it was **your** mistake.

The two big things are time (many years) and a job to return to.

Comment: Another factor is that the actual trip presumably deviated from the itinerary that was proposed in the visa application.  It might be beneficial to explain why the decision was made to change the travel plans, beyond simply mentioning that it was a mistake.